# why azure file share is not mounting on centos versions under 7?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, centos7, centos6.5

Is there any way to create Azure File Share mounts on CentOS versions lower as 7?

Azure documentation recommends centos 7+ for it.

I have tried the same for CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 16.04.Its working fine.
 But for CentOS version under 7 it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> But for CentOS version under 7 it is not working.

It is a by design behavior, because Azure files share requires **SMB 2** dialect which supported by newer CIFS module in RHEL 7.

Pasting the note from Redhat Support Forum:

> "For RHEL when you use the mount command your are using the kernel
>   driver for cifs. The features for cifs commections are tied to the
>   kernel module providing this. You can see details for this with module
>   "man mount.cifs" **The RHEL6 kernel is only capabable of mounting older
>   1.0 smb protocol mounts.** RHEL7 however can mount smb2 version of the protocal since the kernel is using a newer cifs module. On RHEL7 in
>   "man mount.cifs" you will see the options to specify vers= 1.0, 2.0,
>   2.1, or 3.0."

If you want to mount Azure files share to Centos 6, as a workaround we can **update your kernel to 3.1.0 or 4.6**, install the last version of `cifs-utils`, but it is not recommended.

Comment: thanks dude...Its a good explanation for me.Eventhugh kernel upgrade is not recommeneded whether it will work.

Comment: @arunmohan Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Yeah..presently iam working on another thing.if it become success i will post it.Thanks for the help dude

Comment: @arunmohan Have you test it? Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge,you are missing the mount-point directory in the Linux VM to mount the SMB share to.

**In Linux VM:** You need to create a local directory at **/mnt/mymountdirectory**, use the following example to create a local directory:

**sudo mkdir -p /mnt/mymountdirectory**

Then Mount the SMB share to the local directory by providing your own storage account username and storage account key for the mount credentials as follows:

**sudo mount -t cifs //myStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net/mystorageshare /mnt/mymountdirectory -o vers=3.0,username=mystorageaccount,password=mystorageaccountkey,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777**

For more details, refer “**[Use Azure Files with Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux)**”.

And also, you may refer **[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ea783e78-f1a8-45b7-bbb9-f503c2d74f37/azure-storage-mount-error?forum=windowsazuredata)** thread, which addressing your query.

Comment: Note that the OP has no issues with file share mounts, but can only get it working in Centos 7+, not 6.x. Also note that the Azure [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-linux-file-connection-problems) specifically call out using Centos 7+.

Comment: Nope i didnt missed anything like that.I think azure does not support it under 7.